# "'UnsafeRawBufferPointer' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<_>' " in the SQLite.swift when try to use AWSAppSync swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I tried to use AWS Amplify to my app and I followed the steps in the AWS Amplify documentation (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/start?ref=amplify-iOS-btn). But after installing the pods I got the 'UnsafeRawBufferPointer' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<_>' error in my SQLite.swift.
I'm using swift4.  Any guidance for resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The old SDK has been moved to https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/ios/start but if you still see an issue, please provide repro steps and open an issue over in https://github.com/aws-amplify/docs

If you would like to get started with AWS Amplify framework's API plugin (which replaces AWS AppSync), feel free to run through the latest documentation at the link https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/start

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
pod 'AWSAppSync', ' ~> 2.11.1'
```